# pip Access denied Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

When attempting to do absolutely anything using pip in the terminal, I instantly receive the message "Access is denied." No other messages, just "Access is denied." I've tried using administrator terminal, going to different directories, but the same issue happens. I have attempted to run "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" from looking at a solution in a different question but it said pip is up to date and no change occurred. I can get around installing using the "python -m pip install (something)" command but I would like to know the cause of this issue and how to resolve it so it doesn't impede me in future when I try doing something other than installing with pip. Any ideas? Help is greatly appreciated, thank you :)

I'm running Python 3.6 and Windows 10.

So sorry if this is a duplicate question, I've spent a while attempting to see if the answer is already here but for the most part they appear to all be for a different OS or have a different error. Of course, I could have been searching using the wrong query but like Jon Snow, I know nothing, especially about technical stuff.

EDIT: I've gone into the pip.exe files locations and have adjusted security permissions so that any user on my device has full control, still no luck. Many reboots have been done but no luck there either. I can't seem to log into the admin account in terminal as it doesn't accept my password, even though I am the sole account and an admin account.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/42540)?

Comment: you can also try to find where `pip` is located and try to use `chmod` analogue for windows to change who can modify/use/read file

Comment: I tried the first thing, but it won't accept my password... I've found pip, what is chmod analogue?

Comment: I've changed the permissions on all the pip files to allow every account full access, still can't do anything with pip

Comment: Did you find a solution? I now stand with the exact same problem and it came out of the blue. It worked fine then 3 hours later it does not work. From what I gathered the pip file under the scripts folder is protected somehow, but even after setting all user to full control the command cannot be run.

Comment: @SimonChemnitz-Thomsen I never found a solution sorry, I haven't had to use pip since then so I stopped looking into it. Did you try the antivirus disable suggested by Filip? The antivirus could be flagging the file as hostile and locking it.

Comment: @Igneel32 It is ok, I found a solution. It is posted down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with windows defender blocking pip for some reason.

The solution is to make an exception for the python folder (appdata/local/programs) if you used the default install location.

To add an exception:

1. Go to Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security >
   Virus & threat protection
2. Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings, and then under Exclusions, select Add or remove exclusions.

and select the python folder. I also added my virtual environments just in case.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the pip script is installed in the following location by default:

"C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts".

In the terminal, type "path" and press Enter to see if the Python installation path is added. You should see the path:

"C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32"

The Python Environment Variables must be set in order to execute Python commands from the terminal. According to official Python documentation for v3.6.4:

> To run Python conveniently from a command prompt, you might consider
>   changing some default environment variables in Windows. While the
>   installer provides an option to configure the PATH and PATHEXT
>   variables for you, this is only reliable for a single, system-wide
>   installation.
>
> Windows allows environment variables to be configured permanently at
>   both the User level and the System level, or temporarily in a command
>   prompt.
>
> To temporarily set environment variables, open Command Prompt and use
>   the set command:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.6;%PATH%
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
C:\>python
```

> To permanently modify the default environment variables, click Start
>   and search for ‘edit environment variables’, or open System
>   properties, Advanced system settings and click the Environment
>   Variables button. In this dialog, you can add or modify User and
>   System variables. To change System variables, you need non-restricted
>   access to your machine (i.e. Administrator rights)

As a good practice, I always launch cmd with full admin rights as it allows me to execute all sorts of commands/scripts. I have also configured my terminal to open in the Python Scripts directory(above) as I work on Python quite a lot.

Make sure that you have full admin rights to perform tasks on a command prompt. To check all user accounts, type the following in a terminal and press Enter:

```
wmic useraccount get name
```

This will show all user accounts on your computer and help you understand if you launched the terminal with the admin account that has highest privileges.

Once you have found the admin account with highest privileges, run the following command from the terminal:

```
runas /u:hostname\Admin_account_username cmd
```

To get the hostname for your computer, run the following command on the terminal:

```
hostname
```

You will be asked for the administrator password. Proceeding further will open the terminal with the admin profile selected.

If you have recently installed Python and have configuration issues, another great alternative is to install The Anaconda package.

Anaconda ships with the most important(and latest) Python libraries, notebooks, analysis tools, a command prompt called Conda(pre-configured with Python Environment variables) and an amazing documentation. More information below:

> https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the past I have had no trouble with running pip directly from the terminal, and as far as I'm aware I haven't changed anything. The pip file is in the Python path. I've taken a look at the accounts, there's an account called Name which is Administrator but I don't know the password (it isn't any of my passwords) any idea how to get it or switch the admin status to my account? I'm the only one who uses this computer though there's the Name and a Guest account I can't find to remove. Running cmd as admin still won't let me use pip. I've had Python for 2 years, never had this problem before.

Comment: @Igneed32, Please refer to this link: https://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/12/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-10-administrator-account/.

Comment: Modern Windows OS create two user accounts: "the administrator" and "the guest" accounts both of which are disabled by default. The Administrator account(called Name in your case) is used for troubleshooting purposes and has highest privileges. This article shows all the steps you need to enable and setup a password for this account for future use. Let me know the outcome of this exercise.

Comment: Still no change sadly. Strangely when I run 'net users' it does not show up the Name account, it just shows this:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            barti                    DefaultAccount
Guest                    WDAGUtilityAccount

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did all the steps to fix it, eventually I found out that the antivirus program was denying the access to the executable file.

So disabling it worked for me.